# How to display html labels in leaflet for R?

Tags: r, leaflet

the leaflet for R [manual](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html) states, that labels can be simple text as well as html text. However, if I try to add html to a label, it is not formatted as such:

```
leaflet(data=tibble(latitude=41.3828939, longitude=2.1774322, label="<b>TEXT</b>")) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(label=~label)
```

[image: map screenshot]

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
library(leaflet)
library(tibble)
library(htmltools)

leaflet(data=tibble(latitude = 41.3828939,
                    longitude= 2.1774322,
                    label    = HTML("<b>TEXT<br> text</b>"))) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(label=~label)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If you have more than one label, you need to add an `lapply` or `map`.